# Kummer and Tricomi functions for solutions of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Is there a way to have Mathematica give solutions of differential equations in terms of functions with "usual" names such as e.g. *KummerM*, *KummerU* or *Tricomi*, rather than *Hypergeometric1F1* (that one is actually ok) or worse *MeijerG*?

For example, for:

```
DSolveValue[z f''[z] - z f'[z] - a f[z] == 0, f[z], z]
```

I get:

```
z C[1] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + a, 2, z] + 
C[2] MeijerG[{{}, {1 - a}}, {{0, 1}, {}}, -z]
```

But the solution should be expressible in terms of *KummerM* and *KummerU* functions.

Comment: ...but `Hypergeometric1F1[]` is just the name *Mathematica* uses for the Kummer function; similarly, the Tricomi function is called `HypergeometricU[]`. What exactly is your problem here?